# Seaborn boxplot whiskers are missing from just one category

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I've been using the `Seaborn` library to plot box plots. In one instance, I see that the whiskers are randomly missing from one of my categorical variables.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (60,30))

plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'k', linestyle = ':', linewidth = 2)

ax = sns.boxplot(x = 'Neighborhood', y = 'Price difference', data = sf_data_residuals_neighborhoods, 
                 showfliers = False, order = list(neighborhood_order_residuals['Neighborhood']), linewidth = 5)
ax = sns.stripplot(x = 'Neighborhood', y = 'Price difference', data = sf_data_residuals_neighborhoods,
                 order = list(neighborhood_order_residuals['Neighborhood']), jitter = 0.25, size = 15,
                 linewidth = 3, edgecolor = 'black', alpha = 0.5)

# set axis properties
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontname = 'Helvetica', fontsize = 42, ha = 'right')
plt.yticks(fontname = 'Helvetica', fontsize = 42)


plt.xlabel('San Francisco neighborhood', fontsize = 55, fontname = 'Arial', fontweight = 'bold')
plt.ylabel('Actual - predicted price ($M)', fontsize = 55, fontname = 'Arial', 
           fontweight = 'bold')

scale = 1000000; ax.set_ylim(-1000000, 3000000); ax.yaxis.labelpad = 25
ticks = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: '{0:g}'.format(y/scale))
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width = 3, length = 15)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width = 3, length = 15)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticks)
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth = 3)
```

This produces the desired plot, but appears to leave out whiskers for the Potrero Hill category:

[image: Whiskers are present for all categorical variables except 'Potrero Hill']

I've tried manually stipulating the default `whis = 1.5` setting in `sns.boxplot()` but this does not make the missing whiskers appear.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: If there are only 5 points, what would you expect a whisker to show?

Comment: Whiskers show some multiple (default is 1.5x) of the inter-quartile range. As I understand, this ought to be possible to calculate even for a sample size of 5. For instance, in the set `{1,2,3,4,5}` the median is `3`, the quartiles are `Q1 = 2` and `Q3 = 4`, the interquartile range (IQR) is `Q3 - Q1 = 2`, and the whiskers (at `1.5 x IQR`) would be at `0` and `6`. You can see the 'Marina' neighborhood has only 4 points but both the box and the whiskers show up in the plot above, so I don't see the lack of whiskers for 'Potrero Hill' being a result of small sample size.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is rather that two of the points are considered as outliers; hence you end up with only 3 points from which to calculate the IQR and therefore the whiskers are identical to Q1 and Q3.

Comment: Got it. The whiskers will extend to the lowest and highest points **still within 1.5 x IQR** as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot). In this case, there are no points falling within `Q1 - 1.5 x IQR` and `Q3 + 1.5 x IQR`, so no whiskers are drawn.